# HTML string to PDF conversion

Tags: pdf, swift3

I need to create various reports in PDF format and email it to specific person. I managed to load HTML template into string and am replacing certain "custom markers" with real data. At the end I have a fulle viewable HTML file. This file must now be printed into PDF format which I am able todo after following this link : https://www.appcoda.com/pdf-generation-ios/.  My problem is that I do not understand how to determine the number of pages from the HTML file as the pdf renderer requires creating page-by-page.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, I would like to leave this answer here. I also used the same tutorial you've mention and here's what I did to make multiple pages. Just modify the drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer method like this:

```
func drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer) -> NSData! {
        let data = NSMutableData()

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRect.zero, nil)
        printPageRenderer.prepare(forDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, printPageRenderer.numberOfPages))

        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()

        for i in 0...(printPageRenderer.numberOfPages - 1) {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
            printPageRenderer.drawPage(at: i, in: bounds)
        }

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

        return data
}
```

In your custom PrintPageRenderer you can access the numberOfPages to have the total count of the pages